# Understanding if record group is empty in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a record group created from query

```
rg_groups := Create_Group_From_Query(rg_group_name,'SELECT group_name, to_char(ID) FROM GROUPS WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID =''' || :LIST_CONTROL.GROUP_ID || '''');
```

is there a way to check if the query returned 0 rows? I have tried 
`if rg_groups is not null then` however it didn't work

Comment: there is a work around solution, to populate list first, then check the row count of the populated list, although it is decent solution I would still like to understand if it is possible to check after the query executed, not after population of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any check, but you can execute the query as a normal select statement and if you get a no_data_found execption the record group doesn't have any records.

Comment: great work around, but making 2 same queries if the data is returned to be done which is not a desirable result